# Is this Doctor Who story an allegory for the Middle East?

Tags: doctor-who, allegory

In the *Doctor Who* two-parter, *The Hungry Earth* and *Cold Blood*, a group of scientists working in Wales are drilling deep into the Earth.  They reach 21km, deeper than anyone had drilled before, when they're attacked by the Silurians.  The Silurians are asleep deep underground, and the drill was approaching their settlement, where it would destroy them.  This then sets off a conflict that is eventually diffused by The Doctor and the locals.  But a few things remind me of the conflicts between Israel and Palestine:

- The escalation of the conflict.  The Silurians abduct some people, the humans kill some Silurians, and so on.
- The peace talks.  Some of the points of discussion, such as finding a place for settlement.
- The Silurians being a people who've been in a sort of exile, sleeping underground.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't see how you can say it's an allegory based on just those points.  Those are common in any international confrontational situation.  You could use that same info and say it's an allegory for dealing with Hitler in WWII, for example.  (Godwin forgive me for that example!)

Also, many stories involving conflict between two groups will have those features.  The conflict escalates, increasing tension, just as any good story does.  Without conflict, you don't have a story, so that's a "normal" plot ingredient.

As for peace talks, if a story is action oriented, like many war stories, it may not have peace talks since the focus is on winning the war or completing a mission.  (Like *The Dirty Dozen* or *Guns of Navarone*.)  But if the point of the story is stopping a conflict, then peace talks are part of the process and they will almost always be subverted or undermined (excuse the pun, in this case) and the tension is around stopping the saboteurs and getting the sides to trust each other.

The third point is the only one that might be unique, but it could also be seen in different ways.  For instance, it could be an analogy for a fifth column and the invasion coming from the inside.

I have not and cannot find anything online from the powers that be in the Whoniverse that states otherwise, but it seems to me those items alone are not enough to consider it an allegory for just one particular situation.

Comment: @ChrisB.Behrens: It was the most global example I could think of, and I'm not really doing the typical Nazi or Hitler comparison that Godwin generally refers to, but I figured if I didn't invoke Godwin, someone would.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that the writers were inspired by the Israeli-Palestine conflict, but *Doctor Who* being a children's TV programme, and entertainment at that, would only be able to describe it in the most general of terms.

After all, writers are inspired by a variety of materials and the ongoing Israeli-Palestinian conflict would have loomed large in the public imagination.

That this can be the case for script-writers on Doctor Who can be seen in the Christmas Special, *The Doctor, The Widow and the Wardrobe* whose plot-line involves trees being melted down for energy by acid rain and which obviously is riffing off current contemporary concerns with the global climate, the environment and renewable energy concerns.

Thus, unless someone has access to the original writers discussions at the time, it is going to be difficult to say either way.

(Actually, the remit of Doctor Who was educational entertainment from what I recall. Though obviously it is heavily slanted towards the entertainment side it inspires self-education).